# How to clear notification badge count when reinstall the app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, badge

I have integrated the apple push notification for my iOS app. My problem is when I reinstall the app, previous notification badge count is showing even before log in to the app. How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Comment: delete app and set badge to zero in appdelegate didFinishLaunching method

Comment: I want to clear the badge count before user open the app. as soon as installation finish it shows the previous badge number. If user didnt open the app, that previous badge count will be remains untill he open the app

Comment: Look this is only happen because you didnt clear the batch before.When you do the above step it will not happens again only or your device.When application will be install as a fresh it will not show the badge icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried killing the app from the multitasking menu and launching it again?, call here

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

else

it'll only get cleared on launching the app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

return YES;
}
```

**Choice -2**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary* dict = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dict != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched with APNS: %@", dictionary);

            [self clearAPNSNotifications];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{    
    NSLog(@"Received APNS : %@", userInfo);
    [self clearAPNSNotifications];
}

 - (void) clearAPNSNotifications {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Comment: Inorder to happens this my app should open by tapping isnt it? But my problem is when I just reinstall it as soon as even before I open the app it shows the previous badge count

Comment: wy should I clear the badge in didReceiveRemoteNotification?

Comment: I want to clear the badge count before user open the app. as soon as installation finish it shows the previous badge number. If user didnt open the app, that previous badge count will be remains untill he open the app

Comment: ya fine my answer solve your issue, the initially didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called when it is called thats time you can clear the badge count else do nothibg

Answer (score 3):

Updated for iOS 7 and iOS 8 and iOS 9, from Apple's docs:

> On iOS 7 and later, The first time a push-enabled app registers for
>   push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive
>   notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert
>   it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has
>   been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> Delete your app from the device. Turn the device off completely and
>   turn it back on. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the
>   date ahead a day or more. Turn the device off completely again and
>   turn it back on.

For iOS 5 and iOS6:

> Reset the push notifications permissions alert by restoring the device
>   from a backup (r. 11450187). Here are the steps to do this
>   efficiently:
>
> Use the Xcode Organizer to install your app on the device. The key is
>   to install the app for the first time without running it. Use iTunes
>   to back up the device. Run the app. The push notifications permissions
>   alert will be presented. When you want to reset the push notifications
>   permissions alert, restore the device from the backup you created in
>   the first step.

More details please refer to this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: your answer is valuable